# Only allowing a Javascript function to run when the previous function has finished

Tags: javascript, function

I am using two functions, one to move a set of questions to the next question and the other to move a progress bar on. The question that moves the user to the `nextQuestion` overrides the first function and the `progressBar` function doesn't process.

There are no errors shown and I have changed the order or the functions and having one big function all have to the same result. If I run the functions separately both functions work perfect. They originate from @onClick on a button.

I have tried using promises with the same result.

How can I force the `nextQuestion` function only to run when `progressBar` has finished?

**Progress Bar**

```
      progressBar: function(item){

        this.percentQuestion = 100/this.numberQuestions;

        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");

        var numericWidth = elem.style.width.replace(/\D/g,'');

        var currentWidth = +numericWidth;

        var newWidth = +numericWidth + +this.percentQuestion;

        var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
        function frame() {
          if (currentWidth < newWidth) {
            currentWidth++;
            elem.style.width = currentWidth + '%';
          } else{
            clearInterval(id);
          };

          };

       this.nextQuestion(item);

  },
```

**Next Question**

```
     nextQuestion: function(item){

       var newKey = item + 1;

       var y = document.getElementById('question' + item);

        var x = document.getElementById('question' + newKey);

            if( y.style.display === 'block'){
                y.style.display = 'none';
                x.style.display = 'block';
                console.log("Changed");
        };

      },
```

**UPDATE**

```
     nextQuestion: function(item){


       window.setTimeout(function() { function(item){

          var newKey = item + 1;

          var y = document.getElementById('question' + item);

           var x = document.getElementById('question' + newKey);

               if( y.style.display === 'block'){
                   y.style.display = 'none';
                   x.style.display = 'block';
                   console.log("Changed");
           };
       }, 1000);

      },
```

Comment: A running JSFiddle that create your scenario would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean but it looks like you should put `this.nextQuestion(item)` in the `else`, after `clearInterval(id)`.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following do what you want?

```
progressBar: function(item){

    this.percentQuestion = 100/this.numberQuestions;

    var variables = {
        elem: document.getElementById("myBar"),
        numericWidth: elem.style.width.replace(/\D/g,''),
        currentWidth: +numericWidth,
        newWidth: +numericWidth + +this.percentQuestion,
    };

    // This isn't the nicest way of doing this but it should work
    var that = this;

    var id = setInterval(function(){
      frame(item, variables);
    }, 10);

    function frame(item, variables) {
      if (variables.currentWidth < variables.newWidth) {
        variables.currentWidth++;
        variables.elem.style.width = variables.currentWidth + '%';
      } else{
        clearInterval(id);
        that.nextQuestion(item);
      };

    };
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this... I now get a console error of `this.nextQuestion is not a function`

Comment: I have moved `this` to a variable outside of the function and passed item into `frame()` but now getting this error `Cannot read property 'style' of null`. Like item is not being reached in `nextQuestion`

Comment: Just edited the answer, added `var that = this` to outside the `frame()` function. It's a bit of a hack but it will hopefully do what you want.

Comment: Sorry, just read your comment properly. Try the second edit. I haven't checked it but I believe it should give you access to `item`.

Comment: Thanks this now moves to `nextQuestion` but doesnt process `progressBar` and therefore move the progress bar. Do you have any idea why this could be?

Comment: @JamesParsons try the new edit. I'm not that familiar with `setInterval` but there seems to be some weird scoping issue. Hopefully stroing the variables in an object will solve the issue.

Comment: this is now giving me a syntax error creating the object wouldnt the variable object data need to be specified in key:value format?

Comment: @JamesParsons Yes it should be `key: value`. Forgot to change it when editing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout (HTML API)

write nextQuestion function inside the setTimeout method.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    function(item){
        var newKey = item + 1;

        var y = document.getElementById('question' + item);

        var x = document.getElementById('question' + newKey);

        if( y.style.display === 'block'){
            y.style.display = 'none';
            x.style.display = 'block';
            console.log("Changed");
        };
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Can I know who and why someone has upvoted this answer please ?

Comment: I have updated my question, I am currently getting s syntax error. Sorry not used to using Timeout. @Jerome

Comment: @JamesParsons for me you shouldn't use timeout ! That's why I want to know why someone has upvoted this answer and maybe he could explain me why

Comment: Oh okay I understand

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding `this.nextQuestion(item);` inside your function `frame()`

```
var self=this;
function frame() {
      if (currentWidth < newWidth) {
        currentWidth++;
        elem.style.width = currentWidth + '%';
      } else{
        clearInterval(id);
      }
    self.nextQuestion(item);
   };
```

as `frame()` is executed in `setInterval()` you will have `this.nextQuestion(item)` in each interval end.

Comment: Thanks for this... I now get a console error of `this.nextQuestion is not a function`

Comment: i am modifying my answer. Please check it again,

Comment: Please see the answer now @JamesParsons. This should work now.

Comment: We are nearly there I have added `function frame(item)` but still getting `Cannot read property 'style' of null` its like `item` isnt been passed.

Comment: can you come in a chat room so that we can discuss about this more properly.

Answer (score 0):

store this in a variable first then just move
    `this.nextQuestion(item);` to 
     `if (currentWidth < newWidth) {
         currentWidth++;
         elem.style.width = currentWidth + '%';
     } else{
         that.nextQuestion(item);
         clearInterval(id);
     };`

Comment: I now get a console error of `this.nextQuestion is not a function`

Comment: sorry this context has changed. just store this in a variable first.

Comment: We are nearly there I have added `function frame(item)` but still getting `Cannot read property 'style' of null` its like `item` isnt been passed.